# Android Bluetooth GATT timetout with Nordic Thingy:52

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an android application where, after connecting to the thingy52 through the library (thingylib):

```java
BluetoothDevice dev = scanResultList.get(nordicDeviceEntityList.get(pos).getAddress());
thingySdkManager.connectToThingy(getContext(), device, BaseTService.class);
```

I would like to read the Nordic thingy:52 data along with the RSSI value, so in an another activity, when I want to collect the data, i attach a new bluetooth GATT:

```java
private void startDataCollection() {
        for (BluetoothDevice dev : thingySdkManager.getConnectedDevices()){
            thingySdkManager.setConstantLedMode(dev, 1, 100, 1);
            ThingyListenerHelper.registerThingyListener(getApplicationContext(), mThingyListener, dev);
            //e vents
            thingySdkManager.enableMotionNotifications(dev, true);

            gatt = dev.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), true, gattCallback);
        }
}
```

After that on the Accellerometer event callback of the thingylib i get the data and call the GATT for retrive the RSSI value:

```java
@Override
        public void onAccelerometerValueChangedEvent(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, float x, float y, float z) {
            gatt.readRemoteRssi();
        }
```

The problem I find is that after a few seconds (not deterministically, sometimes 5/10s) the device disconnects with error 8 on the GATT (timeout error). If I remove the GATT link before collecting the data, the device does not disconnect and works perfectly. 
I wanted to know if there is a way to prevent a connected GATT from timeout or if I am doing something wrong.

My android log:

```
2020-04-02 13:00:16.607 15336-15396/it.chiarani.beacon_detection D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=9 device=F5:EF:EE:8B:92:7C
2020-04-02 13:00:16.609 15336-15380/it.chiarani.beacon_detection D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=11 device=F5:EF:EE:8B:92:7C
2020-04-02 13:00:16.609 15336-15654/it.chiarani.beacon_detection D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=10 device=F5:EF:EE:8B:92:7C
2020-04-02 13:00:16.610 15336-15654/it.chiarani.beacon_detection V/ThingyConnection: Error 8 : F5:EF:EE:8B:92:7C
2020-04-02 13:00:16.611 15336-15654/it.chiarani.beacon_detection D/BluetoothGatt: close()
2020-04-02 13:00:16.611 15336-15654/it.chiarani.beacon_detection D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=10
2020-04-02 13:00:16.670 15336-15336/it.chiarani.beacon_detection V/ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is on the firmware side of the device, as indicated on this github issue: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Nordic-Thingy/issues/22